# How to correctly perform a count in SQL in example below

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a database sample below:

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId (PK auto)  SessionName
1                    SODJW
```

**Question Table:**

```
QuestionId (PK auto)  QuestionContent  SessionId (FK) refer to Session
1                     Blah             1   
2                     Blah Blah        1
3                     Blah Blah Blah   1
```

**Penalty_Marks Table:**

```
PenaltyAnswerId  PenaltyMarks  QuestionId (FK) refer to Question
1                1             1
2                0             1
3                1             2
4                2             3
5                2             3
```

Now I want to Perform an SQL which counts the `PenaltyMarks` for a Session. So for that to happen, we need to know which `QuestionId` belongs to the `SessionId` and then count the marks.

My question is how can the SQL for this be written to be able to find the `QuestionId`'s within the `SessionId` so then we can count the penalty marks? Reason I am asking this is because it is giving me incorrect count value.

My attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(PenaltyMarks)
FROM Session s
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
INNER JOIN Penalty_Marks pm ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId
WHERE s.SessionId = 1;
```

Comment: What value is it giving you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns number of rows, not the total Count of penalty marks. Also you said that you need to view each session's question with the total penalty marks so you'll have to group by session id and question id.

```
SELECT s.SessionId,q.QuestionId,SUM(pm.PenaltyMarks)
    FROM Session s
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    INNER JOIN Penalty_Marks pm ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId
    GROUP BY s.SessionId,q.QuestionId
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/006ca/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `SUM(PenaltyMarks)` rather than `COUNT(PentaltyMarks)` You will probably also need a `GROUP BY QuestionId`

I am not in a position to test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Count returns the number of rows; you want to use [sum()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), which will add up the values in the rows for you.